# How to position several blocks of information in relation to each other and the page

Tags: html, css

All I want is to make 3 info blocks **centered** and in the sort of a fixed position. I have no idea how to do this. Event the way I placed them next to each other is lame and I think unpractical. What can I do to make it the way I imagined?

Here is the link to the html and css files.

[The Link to Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uCjA3qq_YbJJ7zApPFStm__VnTkBSFoQ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please, provide what you have so far here in the question and not in an outside link.

Comment: Have you investigated CSS flex?